# Can a desert and semi-desert be right beside each other geographically?

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, geography, weather, deserts

One of the countries in my novel is Semi-Arid, but I want it to become more like a hot and dry desert the farther West one travels (like the Sahara). Is this possible?
PS. There are mountains to the east of the semi-arid desert.

Comment: I am confused. Isn't this the most usual case? That is, isn't it normal and expected for deserts to have more or less extensive semi-desertic areas bordering them? Such as, the Sahara and the [Sahel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahel) for example.

Answer (score 7):

This is almost the exact case of nearly every desert on our planet, so yes. This is definitely possible.

Answer (score 2):

As said before, semi-arid regions are ALWAYS close to deserts. They’re not dry enough to be a proper desert, but not wet enough for the usual temperate plants and animals. I don’t think you even need to worry about which particular direction the desert and “not-quite-desert” are in relation to each other; the “desert side” in the east just needs to be in the rain-shadow of high hills or proper mountains, while the “semi-arid side” going west would likely have a river running through it, or it would be just far enough from the mountains to get a bit more rain.